# Python: convert strings containing unicode code point back into normal characters

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string

I'm working with the requests module to scrape text from a website and store it into a txt file using a method like below:

```
r = requests.get(url)
with open("file.txt","w") as filename:
        filename.write(r.text)
```

With this method, say if "送分200000" was the only string that requests got from url, it would've been decoded and stored in file.txt like below.

```
\u9001\u5206200000
```

When I grab the string from file.txt later on, the string doesn't convert back to "送分200000" and instead remains at "\u9001\u5206200000" when I try to print it out. For example:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as filename:
        mystring = filename.readline()
        print(mystring)

Output:
"\u9001\u5206200000"
```

Is there a way for me to convert this string and others like it back to their original strings with unicode characters?

Comment: Does the output contain the quotes? If so, then you probably got a JSON body. Decode it with `json.load(stream)` or `json.loads(string)` – depending on whether you pass a filehandle or string.

Comment: Looks like JSON.  Use `r.json()` instead of `r.text` to automatically decode the JSON body, then write the file with `open('file.txt','w',encoding='utf8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*convert this string and others like it back to their original strings with unicode characters?*

Yes, let `file.txt` content be

```
\u9001\u5206200000
```

then

```
with open("file.txt","rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
text = content.decode("unicode_escape")
print(text)
```

output

```
送分200000
```

If you want to know more read [Text Encodings in `codecs` built-in module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the io module for that. Try and adapt the following code for your problem.

```py
import io
with io.open(filename,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
# process Unicode text
with io.open(filename,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-read-and-write-unicode-UTF-8-files-in-Python

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using Windows. When you open a file, you get its default encoding, which is Windows-1252, unless you specify otherwise. Specify the encoding when you open the file:

```
with open("file.txt","w", encoding="UTF-8") as filename:
        filename.write(r.text)
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as filename:
        mystring = filename.readline()
        print(mystring)
```

That works as you expect regardless of platform.